# How to solve TS2532 Object is possibly 'undefined'. with an Array?

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
interface CompanyInfoProps {
    data: Company;
}
```

Where:

```
declare interface Company {
    /// some stuff
    id: string;
    companyAdmins?: CompanyAdmin[];
}
```

I am trying to do:

```
{data.companyAdmins[0].user.firstName}
```

But I get the error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532
```

I tried `{data.companyAdmins?.length > 0 && data!.companyAdmins[0]!.user?.firstName}` but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just slap some question marks: `data?.companyAdmins?.[0]?.user?.firstName`

Comment: Add as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
{data.companyAdmins?.[0]?.user?.firstName}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Optional Chaining

You need to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to comply with the TypeScript error.

```js
// just suffix `?` character at the
// end of a nullable or optional field

data.companyAdmins?.[0]?.user.firstName
// ---------------^----^---------------
```

Additional **optional chaining** would be required if `user` can be nullable or undefined as well and so on.

```
data.companyAdmins?.[0]?.user?.firstName
// ---------------^----^-----^----------
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is which part of the chain is undefined?
We can't know if `data` might be undefined since we don't know how that's declared but let's assume it's the `data` part in `CompanyInfoProps` and therefore it is not undefined.

`companyAdmins` might be undefined because it's declared optional.

`companyAdmins![0]` might be undefined because the array might be empty but TS will only warn against that if the option `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is set in TSConfig.

We don't know how `CompanyAdmin` looks like but again let's assume that it always has a `user` set and that user always has a `firstName` set.

So overall in your case the one-liner would be:

```
data.companyAdmins?.[0].user.firstName
```

If you're using `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` then it would be:

```
data.companyAdmins?.[0]?.user.firstName
```

However you might want to add some checks:

```
{data.companyAdmins && data.companyAdmins.length > 0 ? data.companyAdmins[0]!.user.firstName : undefined}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ashure typescript that `companyAdmins` is defined 
Try

```js
if (data?.companyAdmins) {
    // your code
}
```